# Open a file whose name is stored inside a variable in python

Tags: python, file

How i can read the contents of a file whose name is stored inside a variable? In this way it gives me error

```
filename=filedialog.askopenfilenames()
fname=Path(filename[0]).name
f=open(fname,"r")
```

It give me a error: `No such file or directory: 'namefile.txt'`

Comment: Your code is good, it seems just that the given path isn't exploitable from where the code is executed, like not same folder or other. And the purpose of using `pathlib.Path` is to avoid using also `open`, don't use both together, use `Path().read_text()` and `path.write_text()`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try:

```
fname = Path(filename[0])
```

Because you need to get the path of file you want to open.